# apcaccess status - connection refused

Tags: networking

running ubuntu 16.
installed apcupsd

UPS is not yet connected. just installing software.

tried running this command: apcaccess status

got: Error contacting apcupsd @ 127.0.0.1:3551: Connection refused

checked community fixes; they are all in place.

could this be because I don't have the UPS USB cable connect yet?

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Steve

Comment: is apcupsd running yet?  `sudo service apcupsd start`

Comment: i wont be able to check till later tonight